# Trying to create a toolbar but the java code doesn't work

Tags: java, android

Well I'm trying to create a toolbar.
I've created a new layout to the toolbar, created a java class file, and I attached the content view to the layout I've created.

When i'm trying to findById, it finds it without any problem, when I try to set a click listener on the views it gives me no errors but when I load the app to my phone and I try clicking the views, it doesn't do a thing, not even in the log.

toolbar.java:

```
ImageView homeIcon, calendarIcon, informationIcon;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.toolbar);

    homeIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homeIcon);
    calendarIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.calendarIcon);
    informationIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.informationIcon);



    homeIcon.bringToFront();
    calendarIcon.bringToFront();
    informationIcon.bringToFront();

    final Intent calendarActivity = new Intent(this, calendarActivity.class);
    final Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    final Intent informationActivity = new Intent(this, informationActivity.class);

    calendarIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {




                startActivity(calendarActivity);

        }
    });
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }
}
```

Toolbar layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/testRel"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/homeIcon"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/iconhome" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/calendarIcon"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/calendaricon" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/informationIcon"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/informationicon"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbarBorder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/toolbar"
            android:background="#AFAFAF"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layouts perhaps...

Comment: @MartinMarconcini added the toolbar layout since you only need that one.

Comment: Did you set `NoActionBar` theme in your `res/styles` ?

Comment: Hmm have you seen [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar)'s documentation? This is not how you'd approach said problem. [Here is the official tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up) coming from Android.

Comment: @BlindKai I did.
The only problem is that the onclicklistener doesnt work.. the toolbar is shown.. its like the toolbar.java isn't connected to toolbar.xml even tho it does finds the icons etc.

Comment: Can you share a sshot of what you want this to look like? It can be a mockup, no need to show the final version. I'm trying to understand... are you attempting to put content inside your toolbar so that you can click it and then a callback is fired?

Comment: Yeah its just a regular toolbar.. with a menu.
For example when I wanna click the home button it will go to the home activity etc.
I've created the toolbar layout and a java class file for making the functions of the toolbar but it seems like it's just not connected with each other